# Purpose of Content-Type undefined in AngularJS FileUpload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

For uploading files from angular to a Spring MVC REST WebService, people seem to be setting Content-Type : undefined header in the AJAX request.

What is the purpose of this type of content-type and is it required by Spring MultiPart?

```
$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
  transformRequest : angular.identity,
  headers : {
   'Content-Type' : undefined
  }
//...
}
```

Comment: fast-forward to 2022 and Typescript 4x, with strict type checking one cannot set the Content-Type to undefined. Setting any other string value wont work. Therefore the content-type header must be omitted entirely. Angular HttpClient will implicitly set it to multipart

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will reset the default header 'application/json' and let the browser fill in the correct Content-Type for us, along with a correct boundary parameter.

Setting in manually to 'multipart/form-data', for example, will fail to add the already mentioned boundary.

Comment: You're right, it was going as application/json and spring was rejecting it as it was not able to recognize request as multipart. Rejecting request based on Content-type seems a bit harsh on part of Spring MVC

Comment: It's not only in Spring, it's the standard header to notify a server that it's about to receive a file.